# How to load data in the collectionview from JSON to Swift by using Alamofire and Kingfisher

Tags: swift, mvvm, uicollectionview, alamofire, kingfisher

I need to get the data from already made JSON file to the Swift. By using MVVM desing I wrote this code in the Repo class

```
 func loadFoods() {
        AF.request("http://example.com/foods/getAllFoods.php",method: .get).response { response in
            if let data = response.data {
                do{
                    let result = try JSONDecoder().decode(ProductsResponse.self, from: data)
                    if let list = result.foods {
                        self.foodList.onNext(list)
                    }
                }catch{
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Here's the code from View Model class:

```
class HomeViewModel {
var foodList = BehaviorSubject <[Foods]>(value: [Foods]())
var frepo = FoodsDaoRepository()

init() {
    loadFoods()
    foodList = frepo.foodList
}

func loadFoods() {
   frepo.loadFoods()
}


func loadPersons(){
    prepo.loadPersons()
}
```

and I wrote this code in the ViewContoller class:

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        searchTextField.delegate = self
        collectionView.delegate = self
        collectionView.dataSource = self
        
        let _ = viewModel.foodList.subscribe(onNext: { list in
            self.foodsList = list
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.collectionView.reloadData()
            }
        })
    
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        viewModel.loadFoods()
    }
```

Foodlist variable takes the data from Food class:

```
class Foods: Codable {
    
    
    var id : Int?
    var name : String?
    var image : String?
    var price : Int?
    var category : String?
    
    
    init(id: Int?, name: String?, image: String?, price: Int?, category: String?) {
       self.id = id
       self.name = name
       self.image = image
       self.price = price
       self.category = category
   }
    
}
```

But it didn't help to get the data from JSON to the CollectionView. It just shows empty collection view cells.

Also how can I get an image by using **Kingfisher** and **Alamofire**?

I tried to explain the problem and wrote a code to expand my question

Comment: I don’t see where you call loadFoods()

Comment: sorry, It's been updated

Comment: I don't know how `foodList.subscribe´ works but I suspect viewDidLoad is executed before the result is returned from the asynchronous call has returned. Maybe add some print statements to see in which order things are executed.

Comment: Updated about foodlist too, Food list is an object of Food class

Comment: I was more thinking about the subscribe function rather than the content of the list but like I said I think you need to investigate in what order things are executed. Perhaps you will need to add a callback function parameter to your loadFoods() function.

Comment: You show `http://example.com....`, 
note Apple requires `https` connection. To use `http`, you need to set the "NSAppTransportSecurity" 
 in your `Info.plist` to allow `http` connection to the server.

Comment: I allowed arbitrary loads. It gives the right amount of cells in the collectionview however  it doesn’t get any data like images or titles from JSON API